# How to setup storm crawler with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I'm trying to set up the stormcrawler with a postgres sql database as the backend. But there is no documentation on what tables need to exist to be able to start the storm crawler.

What tables do I need and which columns do they have? Or is there some way to automatically create the required tables?
Also how do I start the crawler in this mode? because I cannot send in a seed url like the example crawler topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [tableCreationScript](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/sql/tableCreation.script). For the injection of URLs, you can either add them yourself to the table with an insert, as shown in this [tutorial](https://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/index-web-with-aws-cloudsearch.html), or reuse the injection topology from the elasticsearch module and specify the statusupdaterbolt from the mysql module instead. Another approach could be to simply to add a MemorySpout to the topology alongside the SQLSpout.

Comment: Tank you for the answere, maybe you could at a link to this tutorial on the sql readme page?

Comment: I noticed an other issue that it seems that you only support mysql because of the query syntax used. its rather clear with the settings name. but you might best add it to the documentation aswell.

Comment: If there's a more generic way of doing it, your contribution will be very welcome!

Comment: I guess you will have to add a dependency which abstracts away the database used, something like hibernate, i'm a junior engineer with a scala background so i do not really know the good java sql frameworks.